# React Router no me redirecciona correctamente si la URL contiene el mismo path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

me encuentro con un problema con React Router, el cual es que no me actualiza el componente cuando hago un redirect.

Tengo estas dos rutas:

```
            <AppRoute
              exact
              path="/tournament/:id/:name"
              layout={LayoutCollapsible}
              component={Tournament}
            />
            <AppRoute
              exact
              path="/tournament/:id"
              layout={LayoutCollapsible}
              component={Tournament}
            />
```

El problema que se presenta es que por ejemplo, estoy en el torneo:
http://localhost:3000/tournament/5f087ac688fe8b574828d1b6/mega-op-5vs5-lol

Y tengo otro componente, el cual se encarga de hacer un redirect, la cosa es que lo hago y efectivamente me cambia el URL a:
http://localhost:3000/tournament/5f0868690b3f2305e8b36d28/torneo-1vs1-3pm

Pero sigo estando en la misma página, no me actualiza el componente a pesar de que sí hace el Redirect y me cambia el URL en el buscador.

Si me pueden ayudar con esto se los agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo corregí, como el valor que cambia siempre es el id y el nombre, entonces logré esta solución:

```
const id = match.params.id;

useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, [id]);
```